# Bond Pricing between interest dates using excel

Tags: finance

I am doing between coupon payment date bond pricing with excel. I found that when the coupon rate=YTM the price function returns a value below par. For example a bond with coupon rate = 5%; YTM = 5%; frequency = 2; face = $100. The maturity date is 12/31/2030 and settlement date is 9/15/2015. The value returned from excel is always below 100. I have tried changing the basis and none helped.

Answer (score 0):

For purposes of this answer, I am assuming you are using the PRICE() function in Excel, 2008 or later.
'= PRICE(settlement, maturity, rate, yld, redemption, frequency, [basis])

The reason that you get a discount price for this bond is that you are setting the YTM and the coupon equal.  Excel assumes that the yield is expressed in the same compounding basis as the coupon frequency.  So entering 5% for coupon and 5% for yield are both discounted using a semiannual basis.

Because you set the yield to maturity equal to the coupon, with the same compounding basis, the NPV of the redemption + the coupon stream is exactly 100, at any point in time.

Because you have a settlement date during the accrual period, the purchase price will have to include accrued interest.  When you buy a bond during an accrual period, you pay the seller the purchase price times the face amount plus accrued interest from the last accrual date through the settlement date.

Excel assumes that interest is paid in arrears with no delay, so the maturity date 12/31/30 is the final coupon payment.  Therefore, interest is paid on June 30 or December 31.  Buying on 9/15/15, you must pay (depending on your basis) Therefore, you are paying the face value times the price + ( 100 * rate / frequency * A /E ) where A is the number of days from the last coupon date (June 30 to Sep 15th) and E is the number of days in the period from June 30 to December 31.

The only way to get a par price is to settle on the coupon payment date, either June 30 or December 31. Then A = 0, so the price can be par.

See the Microsoft Help for the PRICE() function, the last term in the formula is the discount to par caused by the payment of accrued interest.